# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValues' of undefined | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net-core, state

when i use setValues() function on handleInputChange i get this error:

[image: error-image]

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useForm = (initialFieldValues) => {
  const { values, setValues } = useState(initialFieldValues);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const fieldValue = { [name]: value };

    this.setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue,
    });
  };

  return {
    values,
    setValues,
    handleInputChange,
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

how can i solve this error ?
any response will be appreciated

Comment: removing this  from this.setValues() might solve it

Comment: `useState` returns an array, not an object. Use it as `const [ values, setValues ] = useState(initialFieldValues);` As stated in the above comment, you should not use `this` in the functional React components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useForm = (initialFieldValues) => {
  const [ values, setValues ] = useState(initialFieldValues);

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const fieldValue = { [name]: value };

    setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue,
    });
  };

  return {
    values,
    setValues,
    handleInputChange,
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

In class component you would use `this.setValues`, but in functional components you can directly use `setValues` without `this` keyword.

Change:

```
this.setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue,
    });
```

To:

```
setValues({
      ...values,
      ...fieldValue,
    });
```

Also `useState` returns an array, so you would use it like this:

```
const [ values, setValues ] = useState(initialFieldValues);
```

Please go through the documentation:  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: and 
const { values, setValues } = useState(initialFieldValues);
to 
const [ values, setValues ] = useState(initialFieldValues);
because useState returns an array